# Accessing XML Nodes in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an HTTP response that is formed like this:

```
<records>
<record>
<f id="60">
ANT708-1-BA-M110-001-IFC.PDF
<url>
https://hardermech.quickbase.com/up/bi8vxepu8/g/r9p6/eb6/va/ANT708-1-BA-M110-001-IFC.PDF
</url>
</f>
<f id="276">1</f>
<update_id>1496326605486</update_id>
</record>
</records>
```

How can I access the data value "1" for "f id 276" with Google Script?

Answer (score 1):

How about following sample script?

`XmlService` is used for this script. The detail information is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service.

**Sample Script :**

```
function sample() {
  var data = '\
    <records> \
      <record> \
        <f id="60"> \
        ANT708-1-BA-M110-001-IFC.PDF \
        <url> \
        https://hardermech.quickbase.com/up/bi8vxepu8/g/r9p6/eb6/va/ANT708-1-BA-M110-001-IFC.PDF \
        </url> \
        </f> \
        <f id="276">1</f> \
        <update_id>1496326605486</update_id> \
      </record> \
    </records>'

  var xml = XmlService.parse(data);
  var items = xml.getRootElement().getChild('record').getChildren('f');
  var res
  for (var i in items) {
    if (items[i].getAttribute('id').getValue() == 276) {
      res = items[i].getValue();
    }
  }
  Logger.log(res) // 1 is retrieved.
}
```

The value is in `f` of `record`. Since there are several `f`, it searches the attribute `id` as an array. And the result `1` is retrieved.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.